# How to write a code to made envelope function equal to $\pi$ to result in an X gate?

Tags: qiskit, programming

$$
\hat U_d = \exp\Big( -i\underbrace{\frac{Q}{2}\int_0^T A(t^\prime)\mathop{dt^\prime}}_{\Theta(t)} \hat\sigma_x \Big)
$$

This equation is a Unitary transformation applied to a qubit from time $t = 0$ to time $t=T$. I want the underlined envelope function $\Theta(t)$ to equal $\pi$ to result in an $X$ gate. What code should I write to accomplish this? Should I do frequency sweeps of multiple parameters? I know that a Gaussian pulse should be involved.

Comment: What do you mean by *...to equal π to result in an X gate...*?

Comment: I want to get the underlined part to be equal to pi. If this happens, then the result will be an X gate.

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand. How the result could be a gate? I would expect a quantum state to be the result.

Comment: Maybe the result is a quantum state that had an X gate performed on it.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to provide you with some hints how to implement your unitary operation.

Let's firstly rewrite it as $U_d = \mathrm{exp}(-i\Theta(t)\sigma_x)$ or $U_d = \mathrm{exp}(-i\Theta(t)X)$ (i.e. I replaced the notation $\sigma_x$ for Pauli $X$ gate by symbol $X$).

This means that $U_d$ is in fact $x$ rotation given by formula
$$
Rx(\theta)= \mathrm{exp}\Big(-i\frac{\theta}{2}X\Big)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -i\sin(\theta/2)\\
-i\sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Setting $\theta/2 = \pi/2$ (or $\theta = \pi$) we get
$$
Rx(\pi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi/2) & -i\sin(\pi/2)\\
-i\sin(\pi/2) & \cos(\pi/2)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i\\
-i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
= -iX,
$$
or in other words $x$ rotation with the rotation angle equal to $\pi$ is equivalent to Pauli $X$ gate up to global phase $-i$.

So, if you are able to compute your definite integral $\Theta(t)$, then the operation $U_d$ is simply $Rx(\theta)$ gate with the angle $\theta = 2\Theta(t)$. If $2\Theta(t) = \pi$ then you will get $X$ gate up to global phase $-i$.